# Is it safe to eat old ice-cream?

Tags: freezing, ice-cream

I have an non-opened I ice-cream in the freezer that is older that one year.is it save to eat it?

Comment: Agree that this is a dupe.  Also, can we stop down voting questions? It only serves to discourage.  We have plenty of mechanisms for dealing with questions without needing to down vote.

Comment: @moscafj I don't see them having any downvotes on this question (was it retracted?), but the tooltip says "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful", and while I didn't downvote, I can see this falling under the criteria in some people's opinions.

Comment: @fyrepenguin because I upvoted.  Why discourage any question at all?  Why make a judgement on effort?   What happens when someone whose first language is not English asks a question that is misinterpreted as low effort, when the issue could be one of translation?  We have the ability to close questions, edit questions, and revise questions.  I don't think we should be discouraging questions with a down vote.

Comment: @moscafj ah, I'd looked at their rep and didn't see and (-2), didn't realize it applies those sequentially and not in aggregate.

Comment: @fyrepenguin the language issue was an example.  I don't know if that was the case here.  Point is, it is better to encourage participation in this forum, rather than turn folks away. Reputation is, of course, always low for new participants.